# how to make a selection in this code in order to subtract the appropriate answer from the title in question

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have several different titles "titre" in my database ; how to make a selection in this code in order to subtract the appropriate answer from the title in question ?

```
INSERT INTO `bot_chatbot` (`id`, `titre`, `question`, `reponse`, `reponse2`, `reponse3`, `except`, `regulier`) VALUES
(1, 'sabot', 'prix', '200', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'shoes', 'prix', '180', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, 'product', 'prix', '120', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, '', 'hello', 'Hi, How can I help you?\r\n\r\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(0, '', 'تست', 'ثمن', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


try{
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=c1336779c_neo", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_chatbot WHERE question=?");
    $stmt->execute([$body]);
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $contents[] = [$row['titre'], $row['question'], $row['reponse'], $row['reponse2'], $row['reponse3']];
    }
    foreach ($contents as list($titre, $question, $reponse, $reponse2, $reponse3)) {
        if (preg_match($prix, $body)){
            // SELECT * FROM bot_chatbot WHERE titre=?
            $response = ["data"=>[["message"=>"prix"]]];  
        }
        if(empty($reponse2)){
            $response = ["data"=>[["message"=>"$reponse"]]];
        } 
        if(empty($reponse3)) {
            $a = ["$reponse", "$reponse2"];
            $random = $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];
            $response = ["data"=>[["message"=>"$reponse $reponse2"]]];
        } else {
            $a = ["$reponse", "$reponse2", "$reponse3"];
            $random = $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];
            $response = ["data"=>[["message"=>"$random"]]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not sure what your question means

Comment: It looks like you want to do a select statement that retrieves an answer based on a 'title' .  Sorry, its a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This is precisely what I want to subtract the response of price in the title columns